# Are my NuGet packages compatible with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-standard

I was introduced to c# and visual studio yesterday and I know this is a very simple question. But we are porting code from .NET framework to .net CORE. My job is to install packages/libs that were present in the old code into the new code (The target framework of the solution is 2.1)

But how can I see in NuGet packet manager that a specific library is supported by CORE 2.1? For examples, can I see if this supports CORE on the image, or are all available packages compatible with core 2.0 since this is the target framework?

[image: two muppets]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET Standard is... the standard / spec for .NET compliant languages. Each version of .NET (Core or Framework) is the *implementation* of that standard.

.NET Core 2.0 and up are compatible with .NET Standard 2.0, as per the docs from MS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

[image: .NET implementation support]

In short, you'll want to look for frameworks that are compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 to port to .NET Core 2.2.

Another useful link is an interactive compatibility tool from MS:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard#versions

Comment: hmm..maybe I'm a little slow. So how exactly can I see it in on the image? Or can I assume that all packages/libs there are visible in the NuGet package manager are compatible since I have set the target framework to standard 2.0 for my solution?

Comment: @Xraycat922 basically that: the in-VS NuGet browser will limit packages to what your current solution supports. You can also see `NETStandard,Version=v2.0` in your dependencies list there as a clue.